# Call Code Behind method (function) in RowCreated Gridview's handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to call a Code Behind method inside a Gridview.

This is the Code Behind method that loops through every webcontrol that’s in the form:

```
private void SetupJSdataChange(Control parentControl)
{
    foreach (Control control in parentControl.Controls)
    {
        //Response.Write(control.ID + "<br>");
        if (control is WebControl)
        {
            WebControl webControl = control as WebControl;
            webControl.Attributes.Add("onchange", "InputChanged(this)");
        }
    }
}
```

And I want it to loop through every webcontrol that’s in a RowCreated gridview's handler instead. This is my try:

```
protected void GVTrabajadores_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        foreach (Control control in parentControl.Controls)
        {
            //Response.Write(control.ID + "<br>");
            if (control is WebControl)
            {
                WebControl webControl = control as WebControl;
                webControl.Attributes.Add("onchange", "InputChanged(this)");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

But I get an error that says "the name 'parentControl' doesn't exist in the current context" and I don't know how to handle it.

And this is the Gridview:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GVTrabajadores" runat="server"
            CssClass="table table-hover table-striped"
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = "true"
            GridLines="None"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ShowFooter="true"
            OnRowCreated="GVTrabajadores_RowCreated"
            OnRowCommand="GVTrabajadores_RowCommand">

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nombre">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxNombre" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("nombre") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxNombref" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cerrada">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CBCerrada" runat="server" Checked='<%# (Eval("cerrada").ToString() == "1" ? true : false) %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CBCerradaf" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add a rowCreated event handler to a datagridview?

Comment: I'm asking how to add the same loop inside a rowCreated event handler

Comment: I'm assuming that you've already hooked up GVTrabajadores_RowCreated as an OnRowCreated event handler method. By default, it will only return the row added. What controls do you want to access? What do you want to do? I'll be happy to help, but I need to know "when a row is added, I want to...."

Comment: I edited the question to show you what I want, but there's an error and it says "the name 'parentControl' doesn't exist in the current context" becuase I don't know how to handle it

Comment: I don't mean to be a pain, but I don't get what "RowCreated gridview's handler " is. Can you just tell me what you want to do in words? "When a row is added to my Datagridview, I want to ...."

Comment: You have a datagridview - let's call it myDataGridView. When a row gets added to myDataGridView, you want to.... example: "I want to loop through all the rows of myDataGridView and change the value in Column0 to "YippieDippieDoo"

Comment: When a row is added, I want to loop through every webcontrol that’s in the row and add the onchange attribute

Comment: ok. now we're cooking! What types are your columns - are they all strings? If not, I'll need you to revise your question with your DGV structure

Comment: Perfect! I updated the question and added a gridview as an example

Comment: Just added an answer - hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Note that I used generic event args - if you need them you'll need to change them.

```
private void GVTrabajadores_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gV = sender as GridView;
        for(int i = 0; i < gV.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
          Control c = e.Row.Cells[i].Controls[0];
            string controlType = c.GetType().ToString().Replace("System.Web.UI.WebControls.", "");
            switch (controlType)
            {
                case "TextBox":
                    TextBox t = c as TextBox;
                    t.TextChanged += GVTrabajadores_TextBox_TextChanged;
                    t.AutoPostBack = true;
                    break;
                case "CheckBox":
                    CheckBox cB = c as CheckBox;
                    cB.CheckedChanged += GVTrabajadores_CheckBox_Changed;
                    cB.AutoPostBack = true;
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
    private void GVTrabajadores_CheckBox_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //process change
    }
    private void GVTrabajadores_TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //process changed text
    }
```